# React router jumps over desired target screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm new to react and routing. I have a home page with a video thumbnail, when the thumbnail is clicked I want the app to route straight to the video page, however, it involuntarily jumps to Home -> Video -> Profile. Thus I have to click the back button to end on the screen that I want.

Demonstration below:

[image]

Clearly I am not understanding routing properly, here is my `router.js` The `Auth` key stack is for login registration and that works as intended. The `Main` key stack is where my issues persist

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady)
        return <Splash/>

    return (
        <Router>
            <Scene key="root" hideNavBar
                    navigationBarStyle={{backgroundColor: "#fff"}}
                    titleStyle={navTitleStyle}
                    backButtonTintColor={color.black}
            >
                <Stack key="Auth" initial={!this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                    <Scene key="Welcome" component={Welcome} title="" initial={true} hideNavBar/>
                    <Scene key="Register" component={Register} title="Register" back/>
                    <Scene key="CompleteProfile" component={CompleteProfile} title="Select Username" back={false}/>
                    <Scene key="Login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
                    <Scene key="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} title="Forgot Password"/>
                </Stack>
                <Stack key="Main" initial={this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                    <Scene key="Home" component={Home} title="Home" initial={true} type={ActionConst.REPLACE}/>
                    <Scene key="Video" component={Video} title="Video"/>
                    <Scene key="Profile" component={Profile} title="Profile"/>
                </Stack>
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

On my home page, I have a `TouchableHighlight` with an `onPress` function that runs: `Actions.Video()` to try and move to the Video page. But as you can see it skips right over that page to the Profile page. On my video page, I do have a `Button` element with an `onPress` action of `Actions.Profile()` (which is where I end up after clicking the touchable highlight) but that should only be triggered when I click that grey 'Account' button right?

Edit: Adding Video.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
var { 
    View, 
    StyleSheet, 
    Alert, 
    Platform,
    Text,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    PixelRatio,
    Dimensions,
    Image,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Linking,
    StatusBar } = require('react-native');

import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import styles from "./styles"

import { actions as auth, theme } from "../../../auth/index"
const { video } = auth;

const { color } = theme;

//import YouTube, { YouTubeStandaloneIOS, YouTubeStandaloneAndroid } from 'react-native-youtube';

class Video extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: 'Video',
            headerStyle: { 
            backgroundColor: '#232323',
            borderBottomWidth: 0,
            },
            headerTitleStyle: { 
                color: 'white',
            },
        } 
    }
    state = {
      isReady: false,
      status: null,
      quality: null,
      error: null,
      isPlaying: true,
      isLooping: true,
      duration: 0,
      currentTime: 0,
      fullscreen: false,
      containerMounted: false,
      containerWidth: null,
    };
    onButtonPress = () => {
      //this.props.navigation.navigate('SpotifyLogin')
    }
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.container}
        onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout: { width } } }) => {
          if (!this.state.containerMounted) this.setState({ containerMounted: true });
          if (this.state.containerWidth !== width) this.setState({ containerWidth: width });
        }}
      >        
        <View style={styles.videoMetaContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.videoMetaTitle}>Louis the Child - Better Not (Lyrics) feat. Wafia</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.watchYTBtnContainer}>
        <Button 
          onPress={Actions.Profile()}
          title='Account'
        >
        </Button>

        </View>
        <View style={styles.recentViewerList}>
        <ScrollView
            horizontal={true}
        >
            <View style={styles.recentViewer}></View>
            <View style={styles.recentViewer}></View>
        </ScrollView>
        </View>


      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

export default connect(null, {})(Video);

Comment: Can you post your entire `Video` component?

Comment: @riwu sure thing, I just added it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <Button 
      onPress={Actions.Profile()}
      title='Account'
    >
```

The `onPress` prop should be a function. In this case you have declared a function call, which gets executed as soon as the component renders.

You should declare it as `onPress={() => Actions.Profile()}` or `onPress={Actions.Profile}` so that the function is only called when the `onPress` event is triggered.

Comment: yes that was it, weird that it runs a the action even without a press, thanks for finding my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look and If I'm honest I didn't know that when using the flux you need to include the original references to your other pages in the imports. I see that along with the React-native-router flux, you have not solely depended on your Routes.js file to route to the right pages as you also have links to other parts of the pages that are hard coded into the imports. I'm in a similar situation as you except I have not included import links to the other pages AND routing data as well. Perhaps this is where my issue is coming from.